# NGINX rewrite to file with query parameters

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want nginx to rewrite the url to specific php files that can be determined by the content before the first slash

For example:

1. `testing.com/test` or `test.com/test` would be rewritten to `test.php`
2. `testing.com/test2/variable/another-variable` would be rewritten to `/test2.php?q=variable/another-variable`

I would then use PHP to explode the q `GET` parameter.

What I currently have tried is:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
}
```

This works for example 1 I have displayed above, but returns a 404 for example 2 with a more complicated URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a named `location` with the `try_files` directive to implement one or more `rewrite` statements. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @php;
}
location @php {
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)$ $1.php last;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)/(.*)$ $1.php?q=$2 last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

The `rewrite` statements are evaluated in order. The second `try_files` statement ensures that the PHP file actually exists and is to avoid [passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php).